# sails make route exclusive post

Tags: routes, sails.js

I've added a post route to sails in the routes config file this way:

```
'post /auth/register': 'AuthController.register'
```

That works and I can post to this route. But the get way works aswell. I want to have this route as a exclusive post route. What am I doing wrong there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to turn off the automatic routes sails creates for you.

You can do this by udpating your config/blueprings.js file accordingly

```
module.exports.blueprints = {actions: false};
```

http://sailsjs.org/#!/documentation/concepts/Routes?q=automatic-routes
http://sailsjs.org/#!/documentation/reference/blueprint-api?q=blueprint-routes
http://sailsjs.org/#!/documentation/reference/sails.config/sails.config.blueprints.html